Why doesn't JOOQ cast EnumType variables for Postgres queries?
I face a rare trouble in my service: sometimes JOOQ does not cast enum variables for postgres query, my question is - what could be a reason?
I've investigated how JOOQ builds queries and found out that it should always cast EnumType variables for postgres db in the following way(pay attention to a field status):
select 
    "model"."some_object"."id", 
    "model"."some_object"."number", 
    "model"."some_object"."created_at", 
    "model"."some_object"."deactivated_at", 
    "model"."some_object"."status" 
from "model"."some_object" 
where (
    "model"."some_object"."number" = ? 
    and "model"."some_object"."status" in (?::"model"."entity_status", ?::"model"."entity_status")
) 

But sometimes after restart my service starts throwing the following exception:
select 
    "model"."some_object"."id", 
    "model"."some_object"."number", 
    "model"."some_object"."created_at", 
    "model"."some_object"."deactivated_at", 
    "model"."some_object"."status" 
from "model"."some_object" 
where (
    "model"."some_object"."number" = ? 
    and "model"."some_object"."status" in (?, ?)
) 

ERROR: operator does not exist: status = character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

When it happens, it's usually enough just to restart a service to make it working well. (I guess in that case it builds a right prepared statement for the query)
Repository function looks like:
fun findByNumber(number: String, statuses: StatusSet): List<SomeObject> =
        dslContext.fetch(
            table,
            table.NUMBER.eq(number).and(table.STATUS.`in`(statuses.statusList))
        ).into(SomeObject::class.java)

Jooq version: 3.16.6

"But sometimes after restart my service" - If this behaviour is flaky, I wonder if you're correctly setting up your SQLDialect in your configuration.

@LukasEder SQLDialect is being resolved via jdbc url by default spring config for JOOQ, I checked auto configuration code and theoretically it may throw exception and determine wrong dialect. May be it's what actually happened, will check. Thanks.
